# Edit android executable file

Tags: android, linux

I have android executable files which exactly are ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped. I want to edit them. When I open them with notepad ++, I found words(not code). Then I edit those words and save it. It doesn't work anymore. when it's executed, the segmentation fault returned. Dissembling them doesn't help me. The question is how do I edit those words.

These are the files: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/tok8427bchex2/binary

I just want to edit all "mgyun" to "aungthiha".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the process of opening and saving the binary (executable file) using notepad++ by itself does not affect the binary in some way, your problem probably lies in the fact that "aungthiha" is longer than "mgyun".

Binary files contain low-level code to be executed. This code probably contains jumps to other parts of the code for things like conditionals, loops, and subroutines. The target locations are hardcoded, so if you insert an extra character into the binary, some of the jumps will be pointing to the wrong place (since the right place is now offset), which can cause the binary to not work.

You would probably be successful if you changed "mgyun" to something of the same length such as "12345" because it would not shift anything else around.

See this post for more information: http://everydaywithlinux.blogspot.com/2012/11/patch-strings-in-binary-files-with-sed.html

> Of course there are caveats to this approach. The most significant one
>   is that you can't replace a string with a string that is longer then
>   the original one. Shorter is OK though.

Comment: stackoverflow does not allow me to vote anything. I'm sorry. :(